# WP offload s3 media lite wordpress plugin not able to upload images and files to s3

Tags: php, wordpress, amazon-s3

I am using **WordPress 6.0.1** with **PHP 8.1.8** I set the WordPress to use the **wp offload s3 media WordPress plugin** but it's not working as expected.

When I upload the images it's not going to the s3, instead referencing the server location only.
[image]

I have double-checked for the permissions of the IAM user credentials and the s3 credentials, everything is fine at the AWS level.

**when looking into the debug.log file, I got the following error logs:**

[12-Aug-2022 05:12:34 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  rtrim(): Passing null to parameter #1 ($string) of type string is deprecated in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/formatting.php on line 2772

[12-Aug-2022 05:12:39 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 63

[12-Aug-2022 05:12:39 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 73

[12-Aug-2022 05:12:39 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetSet($key, $value) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetSet(mixed $offset, mixed $value): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 89

[12-Aug-2022 05:12:39 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::offsetUnset($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetUnset(mixed $offset): void, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 102

[12-Aug-2022 05:12:39 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Cookie_Jar::getIterator() should either be compatible with IteratorAggregate::getIterator(): Traversable, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/Requests/Cookie/Jar.php on line 111

[12-Aug-2022 05:12:39 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  http_build_query(): Passing null to parameter #2 ($numeric_prefix) of type string is deprecated in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/Requests/Transport/cURL.php on line 345

[12-Aug-2022 05:12:39 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetExists($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetExists(mixed $offset): bool, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/Requests/Utility/CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 40

[12-Aug-2022 05:12:39 UTC] PHP Deprecated:  Return type of Requests_Utility_CaseInsensitiveDictionary::offsetGet($key) should either be compatible with ArrayAccess::offsetGet(mixed $offset): mixed, or the #[\ReturnTypeWillChange] attribute should be used to temporarily suppress the notice in /var/www/html/wordpress/wp-includes/Requests/Utility/CaseInsensitiveDictionary.php on line 51.

Answer (score 2):

After an extensive amount of research, I have finally solved this issue. This was an issue that was related to the AWS S3 bucket only.

I have to go inside the respective bucket and in the **permission**, section goes to the **Object ownership** section and tick the **ACLs enabled** option, and check the "**Bucket owner preferred**" checkbox as shown in the screenshot below.
[image]

And the issue will be solved with images starting to be uploaded to s3 directly.

[image]